# Help with design a facebook integration for my website.. App or Page?

Tags: facebook-like

I´m building a website to post my own videos using JW Player running my own ads as overlay.
www.planetsnowmobile.com
All my videos will be

**Instead of register my own users, having my own forum etc etc I want to use facebook to interact with my visitors:**

- Individual discussions/comments on individual films instead of my own comment/forum-function
- facebook-like-button for individual films (so induvidual like buttons for individual films)
- Share induvidual films
- Grab location from every unique visitor

**Where do I start?**

- Do I need to create an application or should I use a Facebook "page"?
- Maybe both?
- I see that i can add an application to a "page" but what does that really do? How do I use that?

What would be the best way for me to do this?

I already have a Facebook "page" for my website and I just created an App as well.

- Which one should I use?
- Do I need both?
- What is the difference?

I know that I can create a like button for a website address on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

- But can I monitor that like button from example an application if I can connect them somehow?
- Is that something I want to do?
- My Facebook-page already have a user-base where my Facebook-application does not.. is my best option to delete my "page" and start all over with my "application"?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for information about the entire Facebook platform and integrating it in to your work. I would suggested reading their documentation and doing some searches for the things you're interested in, then you can do some testing on your own and figure out what works best for your project. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: Tnx for your reply..

Ok.. might look like I´m asking about everything I suppose.. 

More direct..
- I want to build a community for my website using Facebook-users
- I dont understand Apps VS Pages (or should they be used together?)

I have been reading for 2 days now getting no-where on that question.

Comment: Edit: moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`App` is their encompassing term for any application that uses their API, this could be on Facebook or on your own personal website - these require an API key to make authenticated calls for users. `Pages` are FB's own in-Facebook content that users have created, like page for a business located at facebook.com/mybusiness. It sounds like you already have a website and want to add Facebook functionality to it, so you don't want to make another Page. You may not even need to create an App. Things like comment boxes and like buttons can be dropped in as stand-alone copy-and-paste widgets. You can track the like button by enabling FB insights for your website.

So like you noticed you can add a like button to your page using the social plugin from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - similar to the like button you can add comment boxes with the plugin at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

You can track the results from these plugins by adding your website to Facebook's analytics (`Insights`) at http://www.facebook.com/insights/

Most of these things are powered by the opengraph metadata in the headers of your website's pages. You can read up on what tags FB uses here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Everything at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ can be used without an application or page ID, and is very good about being responsive to the page they are hosted on: you can add a like button to your video view template without a defined URL in the like button's parameters, and it will automatically direct any likes to the url of the currently viewed video.

You could also direct a like button to point to your existing FB Page, in which case any likes collected from it would be added to the Page's total. Most companies that have a home-page like button do this, so their likes all accumulate to a single total for their business.

Hope that helps.